# Need a batch file that deletes all directories with an integer for a name (314244), and were modified at least 120 days ago

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to run a batch file on startup for a given group that will delete all folders in a specific path (C:\Users).

NOTE: Only directories that are named with integers should be deleted.
NOTE: Only delete the above directories if they were last modified over 120 days ago.

The only thing that I can get to work is to delete ALL folders at least 120 days old. However, it deletes everything...even my folders with Strings (admin, public, etc.).

Help, please! :)

```
ForFiles /P C:\users  /D -120 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE echo RD /Q @FILE &RD /Q /S @FILE"
```

Comment: Could some of the folder names start with `0`? In which range are the integer names?

Comment: Actually, they can start with any integer 0-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether the current file is numeric, you could use `set /A` and try to convert the current item to a numeric value, and then do a string comparison of the original item and the converted number. Together with `forfiles`, this results in the following command line:

```
forfiles /P "C:\Users" /M "*" /D -120 /C "cmd /V /C > nul 2>&1 (if @isdir==TRUE ((set VAR=@file) & set 0x22VAR=!VAR:0x22=!0x22 & set /A 0x22NUM=1!VAR!0x22 & if 0x22!NUM!0x22==0x22!1VAR!0x22 ((> con echo @path) & rd /Q /S @path)))"
```

The above command line is hardly understandable, so here is the code inside of the `cmd` instance in a more legible form (of course this cannot work outside of `forfiles`, as there is no `@file` or `@path` variable):

```
> nul 2>&1 (
    if @isdir==TRUE (
        (set VAR=@file)
        set "VAR=!VAR:"=!"
        set /A "NUM=1!VAR!"
        if "!NUM!"=="1!VAR!" (
            > con echo @path
            rd /Q /S @path
        )
    )
)
```

What happens here? Well, I tell you:

- `> nul 2>&1` constitutes a redirection and tells the entire adjacent code block `()` to not output any messages to the console (neither standard nor error messages);
- `if @isdir==TRUE` filters out all files, so only directories are processed;
- the first `set` command assigns the current item `@file` to variable `VAR`; `@file` is expanded to a string enclosed in `""`, the second `set` command removes such; the third `set` command does the conversion to a numeric value as the switch `/A` is given, and stores the result in variable `NUM`; the prefixed `1` prevents trouble with numbers starting with `0` (such are interpreted as octal ones);
- `if "!NUM!"=="1!VAR!"` constitutes the string comparison; if the converted number equals the original item plus the preceding `1` literally, `@file` is a pure number (remember that `VAR` contains the value of `@file` with surrounding `""` removed);
- `> con echo @path` just displays the path of the current item (explicit redirection to console to actually see it on screen), `rd` does the actual deletion of the directory (tree);

This approach works even with negative numbers, that is, numeric items with a `-` at the beginning. It will fail with numbers less than `-2^31 = -2147483648` and greater than or equal to `+2^31 - 1 = +2147483647`.

Comment: The above line is ugly, but the explanation makes sense. I'll try it and comment

Comment: Yes, I know, it looks terrible; the advantage is that there is only a single call of `forfiles`, which might slightly improve the overall performance as the (date) filtering does not need to be done that often; placing `forfiles` within another loop construct which hands over every single item to `forfiles` leads to the fact that the date filtering needs to be accomplished as often as the number of items...

Comment: Sorry for not replying to your comment, this worked beautifully. Thank you for your help. We have to do this annually to over 150 labs machines in our building to remove old profiles on machines that have small storage capacities. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`FORFILES` only accepts filemasks (like `*.*`) and not regular expressions, which is what is needed to detect "directories that are named with integers". For this you can use a combination of `FOR /F` and `FINDSTR`. On the other hand, no (standard Windows) utility I know of, can do the "last modified over 120 days ago" filtering, except for `FORFILES`.

Putting that together (and with your safety net of `ECHO`ing the result first) we get:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET TEST=C:\
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /A:D C:\Users ^| FINDSTR /R "^[0-9][0-9]*$"') DO (
    FORFILES -pC:\Users -m%%G -d-120 -c"ECHO RD /Q C:\Users\\%%G & RD /Q /S C:\Users\\%%G"
)
```

**Note:** You need to put this code into a batch file for it to work.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It first looks at the directory name to start with an integer, then looks at the date and removes. Bravo!

Comment: @ProgrammerInTrainingDS Glad to help :) Please accept the answer if it worked out for you...

Comment: @ProgrammerInTrainingDS I just noticed you said "start with an integer" in your comment. From your question, I got the impression that directory names consisting *only* of numbers were relevant. If starting with an integer makes them relevant, exchange `^[0-9][0-9]*$` with `^[0-9]`.